# Negative coefficients in regression for positive coefficient of correlation

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, correlation, coefficients

I am building a multiple linear regression model using python. I found the correlation coefficients between all the independent variables and the dependent variable. They were all greater than 0.5. However, the equation given by the regression model has a few negative coefficients. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

The situation you describe is not impossible. The key is to analyse the correlation between your independent variables. If there is a strong correlation between two of them, it is possible that one of these two has a negative coefficient in your linear regression.

For instance, take the following example where you want to predict `y` using `x1`and `x2` as independant variables :

- Let's say that `y` is deterministic and follows `y = x1 + 2 * x2`.
- Let's say that `x2`is also deterministic and that `x2 = 0.1 * x1`

Then, your linear regression has an infinite number of possiblity, you could say that `y = 1.2 * x1 + 0 * x2` as well as `y = 0 * x1 + 12 * x2` or `y = 2 * x1 - 8 * x2`. In the latter case, although there is a positive correlation between `y`and `x2`, you have a negative coefficient in your linear regression. There is no error, nothing wrong.

That is why you should not jump to conclusions and say that because there is a positive slope in your linear regression model, that necessarily means that there is a positive correlation between the independent and the predicted variable. And of course, that you cannot infer any causation from your results.

I hope that answers the question.

Comment: It does. Thank you for explaining it so well.

Comment: In that case, is there any way to treat the independent variables as a non deterministic value? I know that some of them have high correlations among themselves but I also know that it does not imply causation.

Comment: Well, I gave the easiest example to understand. The intuition stays right with non-determinisitc values. And actually, the random variations would define how the linear regression chooses the coefficients among the infinite possibilties of the non-deterministic case.

Comment: If some independent variables are too correlated, I would suggest you remove one of them. It should not deteriorate too much the results, but would reduce the risk of overfitting.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't answer your comment, I'm not sure I understood your question.

Comment: If we take the example you gave (y=x1+2*x2), is there a way for the model to just use this as the equation without taking x2=0.1*x1 into consideration ?

Comment: I think that if you already know this equation, you don't need any linear regression model ;). If you just know that two variables are proportional to each other (or very close to being so), you can remove one of them from your independent variables, that should not impact the quality of your Linear Regression

Comment: I don't know the equation but with the available data, I know that it should all be positive. I actually have to find the coefficient for each individual variable so I can't remove them either.

Comment: Oh, I see, is zero acceptable as a coefficient or do they need to be strictly positive ?

Comment: Zero will be fine too but i think it would be better if they're all positive even if the number is close to zero

Comment: Is it possible to get something like that?